# Normal Distribution P(Z= 1.75)

Tags: normal-distribution

My textbook does not have any solution for this type of problem but it asks it. I cant find anyway to do it even with google...... I do not understand, my professor gave the solution and it is 0. I have no idea how that is

Comment: For continuous distributions, like the standard normal, it doesn't actually make sense to look at the probability of taking a particular value. However, you can use lookup tables to see P(Z < 1.75), or to calculate the probability that the random variable will lie in a particular interval, like P(0 < Z < 1.75).

Answer (score 3):

For [continuous] random variables $Z$ with a density $f$, we always have $P(Z=z)=0$.

One way to see this is to note that the probability of any interval $(a,b)$ is $P(a<Z<b) = \int_a^b f(x) \mathop{dx}$. If you imagine shrinking down this interval to a point $z$, then in the limit you will get $P(Z=z)=0$.

Comment: So any P(z = ) will always yield 0?

Comment: @ricefieldboy Yes, for continuous random variables.